# How to have hashed passwords in Firebase using Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, passwords, firebase-authentication

I was following an Uber clone [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZnKNMsnM5o&list=PLZhNP5qJ2IA2z5ntmXoWhn8eCRstWfvu2&index=11). I can get log in, registration, and logout working, but the passwords don't seem to be hashed; I can see them plainly in my Firebase database.

Here is my code. First login/sign up/logout function saved in a 'plugins' folder separate from controllers.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

typealias  LoginHandler = (_ msg: String?) -> Void;

struct LoginErrorCode {
    static let INVALID_EMAIL = "Invalid email, please provide a real email address";
    static let WRONG_PASSWORD = "Wrong Password, Please Try Again";
    static let PROBLEM_CONNECTING = "Problem Connecting to Database. Please Try Later";
    static let USER_NOT_FOUND = "User Not Found, Please Register";
    static let EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE = "Email Already In Use, Please Use Different Email";
    static let WEAK_PASSWORD = "Password Should Be At Least 6 Characters";
}

class AuthProvider {
    private static let _instance = AuthProvider();

    static var Instance: AuthProvider {
        return _instance;
    }

    func login(withEmail: String, password: String, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.handleErrors(err: error as! NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler);
            } else {
                loginHandler?(nil);
            }
        })
    } //login func

    func signUp(withEmail: String, password: String, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.handleErrors(err: error as! NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler);
            } else {
                if user?.uid != nil {
                    // store the user to database
                    DBProvider.Instance.saveUser(withID: user!.uid, email: withEmail, password: password)
                    //log in the user
                    self.login(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, loginHandler: loginHandler)
                }
            }
        })

    } //sign up func

    func logOut() -> Bool {
        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
            do {
                try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut();
                return true;
            } catch {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    private func handleErrors(err: NSError, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {
        if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: err.code) {
            switch errCode {
            case .errorCodeWrongPassword:
                loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WRONG_PASSWORD);
                break;
            case .errorCodeInvalidEmail:
                loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.INVALID_EMAIL);
                break;
            case .errorCodeUserNotFound:
                loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.USER_NOT_FOUND);
                break;
            case .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse:
                loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE);
                break;
            case .errorCodeWeakPassword:
                loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WEAK_PASSWORD);
                break;
            default:
                loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.PROBLEM_CONNECTING);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} //class
```

And the controller:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class SignInVC: UIViewController {
    private let DRIVER_SEGUE = "DriverVC";

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {

        if emailTextField.text != "" && passwordTextField.text != "" {
            AuthProvider.Instance.login(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, loginHandler: { (message) in
                if message != nil {
                    self.alertTheUser(title: "Problem With Authentication", message: message!);
                } else {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.DRIVER_SEGUE, sender: nil)
                }
            });
        } else {
            alertTheUser(title: "Email And Password Are Required", message: "Please enter email and password");
            }
           }


    @IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any) {
        if emailTextField.text != "" && passwordTextField.text != "" {
            AuthProvider.Instance.signUp(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, loginHandler: { (message) in
                if message != nil {
                    self.alertTheUser(title: "Problem With Creating New Account", message: message!)
                } else {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.DRIVER_SEGUE, sender: nil)
                }
            })
        } else {
            alertTheUser(title: "Email And Password Are Required", message: "Please enter email and password");
        }
    }


    private func alertTheUser(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert);
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil);
        alert.addAction(ok);
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


} //class
```

Comment: Is that something that I'll have to add myself? It's not a part of FirebaseAuth?

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `updatePassword(_ password: String, completion: FirebaseAuth.FIRUserProfileChangeCallback? = nil)` on `FIRUser`.